# Has anyone seen this PDE I've run into

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I've run into the following PDE as a linearization of another PDE,
$$u_t=u_{xxxxx}$$
where $u=u(t,x)$. It looks sort of trivial, but I know virtually nothing about PDEs higher than degree two. Has anyone seen this before? Obviously there are trivial solutions like $e^{t+\zeta x}$ with $\zeta^5=1$ or $sin(t+x)$.

It would be nice if this has a name - or if there is a name for general equations of the form $u_t=u_{x\cdots x}$, like the order-$n$ Zimbabwe-Caltrop equation or something. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular problem, you can use [Method of Separation of Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations). 
$$
u = XT
$$
where $X = X(x)$ and $T = T(t)$. PDE becomes
$$
XT' = X^{(IV)}T
$$
or after some manipulations
$$
\frac {T'}{T} = \frac {X^{(IV)}}{X}
$$
Typical move here is to notice that RHS and LHS are functions of different variables, which means the only option they can be equal is if they are constants. So
$$
\frac {T'}T = \frac {X^{(IV)}}X = \lambda^4
$$
$\lambda$ is raised to the $4^{th}$ power for the sake of simplicity. First equation will give widely known solution 
$$
T = T_0 \exp \left( \lambda^4 t \right)
$$
Second equation has a [Characteristic Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_%28calculus%29) of the form
$$
k^4 - \lambda^4 = 0
$$
which has a set of solutions
$$
k_{1,2} = \pm \lambda \\
k_{3,4} = \pm \lambda i
$$
General solution of latter ODE is a superposition of corresponding exponents
$$
X = X_1 \cos \lambda x + X_2 \sin \lambda x + X_3 \cosh \lambda x + X_4 \sinh \lambda x
$$
so overall general solutions is
$$
u = T_0 \exp \left( \lambda^4 t \right)\left( X_1 \cos \lambda x + X_2 \sin \lambda x + X_3 \cosh \lambda x + X_4 \sinh \lambda x\right)
$$
To find unknown $\lambda$ and coefficients $T_0, X_i, i = 1,2,3,4$, one needs to use Initial and Boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the exposition. I suppose that if these equations can be solved via separation of variables, they are not notable enough to be named.

Comment: The PDE has order 5 in $x$ so the procedure is exactly the same but the solution is a lot uglier now.

Comment: @FixedPoint ooops, lost one $x$ I guess :) In that case, you'll get bunch of complex exponents.